# how to send local notifications when app is terminated in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to implement local notifications in my chat app, that whenever User A send message to User B then I want to send notifications,, it is possible to send local notification when the app is terminated,, As you know guys firebase functions are paid so I am trying to work with local notifications...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try sending notifications thru Firebase HTTP API just provide the fcmtoken of the receiver.

Comment: thankyou Kei Credo

Comment: Can you explain that how can i integrate Firebase HTTP API in my project and how can i use it????

Comment: Here's the link for the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages... you can try it by using your own api and within it call the firebase rest api with curl.